# A geography word

Tags: single-word-requests, geography

What is the word for the point when a river leaves a mountain to flow out onto a plain or such?

Comment: Do you mean the “source”?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about a river that flows down the side of a mountain and then flattens out, like a log flume, and I don't think that's how rivers work. Maybe a photo of what you're talking about would help.

Comment: You might get better results if you search for such a word on geography sites. That said, it'd be nice to have more context. Are you translating from another language? Are you writing something scientific (say about an animal's habitat) or something descriptive (say for fiction) or about some human settlement (or something else)? Is this an adjective or a noun that you know about already but can't remember the exact term or is it more vague than that?  Is the word a feature of the river itself, of the mountain, or of the plain (or some combination)?

Comment: @Mitch a "better" result? Is my answer wrong then? The question seemed  clear to me.

Comment: @WeatherVane Your answer _sounds_ right to me but I am uncertain because technical vocab can be so very specific. The OP asks for river/mountain/plain. But 'debouchment' is much more general than that. There may a specific word for what the OP is describing and using debouchment may be inappropriately too general. This is like asking here what you call a vector space where the field is relaxed to allow a more general ring (it's a module); sure, you may be lucky enough that a mathematician comes by and answers it, but it sure is obscure for general English.

Comment: Also, I apologize, I didn't mean to say yours wasn't good, I was commenting before I looked at the answers.

Comment: @Mitch it's true, I didn't know the term, but I was reading up on rivers which flow out of a mountainous region onto a plain, sometimes quite abruptly, and (unlike what Jim Perris thinks) there are many such. The Wikipedia page for the Ganges contained the word, which linked to the page in my answer.

Comment: Here's the context: On the eleventh day, Talmido left the Inn and Zariaspa, heading southeast toward the Qonduz River drainage entrance. The Hindu Kush was a mountain range with a fierce reputation but it was one Talmido was familiar with.

Answer (score 2):

I think the term you are looking for is **debouch** or **debouche**. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debouch) says

> In the geography of rivers, streams, and glaciers, a debouch, or debouche, is a place where runoff from a small, confined space emerges into a larger, broader space.

and this

> Some examples are: where a river or stream emerges from a narrow constraining landform, such as a defile, into open country or a wider space.